# How to convert html to pdf using pdf4net

Tags: .net, html

The current client has approved only to use pdf4net software to convert a HTML tag to pdf. Any code sample will be of great help.

Thanks
Karthey

Comment: Did you check the [samples](http://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/samples.htm)?

Comment: They do have several examples.  More on beautifications of pdf. nothing there for converting an HTML to  pdf.

Comment: The 'Multicolumn HTML text and images' example demonstrates some HTML formatting capabilities. http://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/samples.htm